# Powershell: Start-Process doesn't pass arguments to cmd.exe

Tags: powershell, cmd, windows-10

These are the commands run in a powershell console (Windows 10):

```
$username = 'Username'
$password = 'Password'
$securePassword = ConvertTo-SecureString $password -AsPlainText -Force
$credential = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential $username, $securePassword
Start-Process powershell.exe -Credential $credential -WindowStyle Hidden -ArgumentList "Start-Process cmd.exe -Verb RunAs -ArgumentList 'value'"
```

These commands work fine except that once you open cmd.exe as administrator via another user, by running this command:

```
echo %1
```

It gives me back:

```
%1
```

Literally. Instead I expect:

```
value
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Any reason why you're not doing this instead: `Start-Process cmd.exe -Credential $credential -ArgumentList "echo value" -Verb RunAs`?

Comment: Because Credential and Runas cannot be in the same command.  
`Parameter set cannot be resolved using the specified named parameters.`  
I see upvotes for the comment, so it works for you?

Comment: Can anyone reply to my comment?
Does the command proposed to you work?

Comment: No, they cannot be used together. Not sure why the upvotes on that comment.

Comment: @Abraham, while it is certainly tempting to make the simplification you're proposing, it cannot work even _syntactically_, as has been pointed out. It is so tempting that I too initially up-voted your comment (which I cannot undo anymore), along with 4 others. Can I suggest removing the comment, so as to avoid confusion?

Comment: @Mario, while the absence of `/c` or `/k` preceding a command passed to `cmd.exe` explains why your code doesn't work as intended, I'd expect a different _symptom_,  namely the command getting _ignored_ altogether and simply an _interactive session_ being entered.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I just [answered a question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69703042/584676) where the solution can be found using the script I provided there, with a few modifications, and invoking the chain of commands in a particular way:

**RunAsProxy.ps1**

```
# First arg should be the script path
$script = $args[0]

# Rest of args should be any script parameters
$scriptArgs = $args[1..$args.Count] -join ' '

$startProcessArgs = @{
  Wait = $true
  Verb = 'RunAs'
  FilePath = 'cmd.exe'
  ArgumentList = "/c ""$script"" $scriptArgs"
}
Start-Process @startProcessArgs

exit $LASTEXITCODE
```

Then call **RunAsProxy.ps1** as follows as the user you want to run as, then elevate:

```
$command = "Command_you_want_to_run_from_cmd.exe"
$arguments = "any arguments to the program"
Start-Process -Cred $credential powershell.exe "-File ./RunAsProxy.ps1 $command $arguments"
```

The way this works is pretty much what you attempted, but using a pre-defined script to handle the elevation. But as you discovered you cannot call `-Credential` and `-Verb` in the same invocation on `Start-Process`. So this works more easily than defining the code in-line:

1. Run `RunAsProxy.ps1` as the target user
2. RunAsProxy.ps1 will run `cmd.exe` with the provided arguments and elevate the process.

Note that if `RunAsProxy.ps1` is not in the current directory you would need to provide the relative or full path to it.

Answer (score 0):

The **only problem** with your approach was that you **forgot to use `/c` or `/k` with [`cmd.exe`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/cmd)** in order to make it *execute a command* on startup:

- **`/c`**: `cmd /c $someCommandLine` executes the command(s) represented by `$someCommandLine` *and then exits*.

  - Note that this means that the console window *automatically closes* on exit, if the `cmd.exe` process owns the window (which is the case here);
  - Appending  `& pause` to the command string would keep the window open until the user presses a key, given them a chance to see the output.
- **`/k`**: `cmd /k $someCommandLine` executes the command(s) *and then keeps the session open*, i.e. enters an interactive session.
- Note: If you precede your command(s) with *neither* `/c` nor `/k`, `cmd.exe` *ignores* them and simply enters an interactive session (as it does if you execute `cmd.exe` without arguments altogether).

The assumption is that `'value'` in your code is a placeholder for command(s) you want `cmd.exe` to execute in the elevated session.

Here's a **simple example** (which uses a [here-string](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Quoting_Rules#here-strings) to obviate the need to escape quotes embedded in the string) that uses `cmd /c` to execute a sample command followed by `pause` to keep the window open until the user presses a key (using `/k` would be more problematic from a security perspective, as you'd enter an *interactive* session with admin privileges).

```bash
# Note: Prompts for the admin credentials first, then requires confirmation
#       of the UAC prompt when the elevated process is launched by the 
#       nested Start-Process call.
Start-Process -Credential (Get-Credential $username) powershell.exe `
  -WindowStyle Hidden `
  -ArgumentList @'
   Start-Process -Verb RunAs cmd.exe -ArgumentList '/c echo I am %USERNAME% & pause'
'@
```

---

Since it isn't readily obvious to others why your code involves *two* - nested - `Start-Process` calls, let me provide **context**:

- Your code runs an *elevated* (run-as-admin) command with a *different user identity*, presumably because the current user cannot request elevation as him/herself, due to not being an administrator.

  - Just to provide the obligatory security warning (I hope your code is just sample code): storing plain-text passwords in scripts is *not safe*, let alone an *administrator*'s password.
- Doing so requires *two* [`Start-Process`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/Microsoft.PowerShell.Management/Start-Process) calls - one nested inside the other, because the `-Credential` parameter (requesting a specific user identity) can syntactically *not* be combined with `-Verb RunAs` (requesting elevation):

  - The outer one, with `-Credential`, starts an (invariably) *non-elevated* process as the target user. This process is a *transient, auxiliary* process (which is why you're running it *hidden* with `-WindowStyle Hidden`).
  - The inner one, from the auxiliary process, with `-Verb RunAs`, then starts an elevated process (visibly) *as that user*.

---